"TSA regulations state that travellers are allowed one personal item and one carry on"?
I'm a frequent flyer on Jetblue, and every time I fly on that particular airline, an announcement is made that states, "As a reminder, TSA regulations state that passengers are allowed one personal item and one carry on. Everything else must be checked underneath the cabin." (It may not be those exact words as I'm typing from memory of course).
My question is: is that an actual policy implemented by the TSA? I find that difficult to believe because TSA is a government agency that is responsible for maintaining airport security; a passenger carrying extra baggage on board could pose a storage issue on the plane, but I have a hard time believing that this situation could be construed as a security/safety issue.
Yet at the same time, however, most (if not all) Jetblue gate agents repeat this same line, suggesting that it is part of Jetblue's preboarding "script." I would not think that a major airline would officially include a line that falsely attributes its own baggage policy to the TSA.
So what's going on here? Could anyone point me to a specific TSA regulation that sets the maximum number of on-board bags/items to two?

I'm not sure. Business class passengers may get two carry-ons and two personal items.

“I have a hard time believing that this situation could be construed as a security/safety issue.”  We're talking about the TSA here…

@gidds - Airlines have always pushed this "policy." After 9/11, airlines were asked for suggested changes to airline security policies and this rule is one of the ones that airlines "suggested." It had, and has, nothing to do with security but with airlines' operations.

If you search the TSA's website for "one personal item" you will find this page of "Travel Tips" (which is often copied into holiday-specific press releases). At the bottom of Tip #5, "Be aware of new checkpoint screening technology," is the note:

TSA reminds you that you may only bring at maximum one carry-on bag and one personal item through security screening.

So this is at least a somewhat official rule, although it has to do with the security screening process only. Supposing someone has managed to get more than one of each through the security checkpoint, the TSA doesn't seem to care what happens afterward.
But the FAA does regulate carry-ons. 14 CFR 121.589:

(a) [...] no passenger may board an airplane if his/her carry-on baggage exceeds the baggage allowance prescribed in the carry-on baggage program in the certificate holder's operations specifications.

FAA Order 8900.1, Volume 3, Chapter 18, Section 3 includes (starting on page 20) some information on what the OpsSpec must contain regarding carry-on baggage, but it does not have specific information. I have seen references to a "template" OpsSpec but I haven't been able to find that, nor have I been able to find a freely available copy of JetBlue's specific OpsSpec. But my suspicion is that JetBlue's own OpsSpec is the source of the "one carry-on and one personal item" rule, and I also suspect that that is the default rule for all carriers.

Does carry-on luggage generally go through TSA security screening on arrival? I haven’t been to the US for about seven years, but I don’t recall that ever happening to me (there or anywhere else). And if, like elsewhere, luggage only goes through security screening when moving airside before departure, what is the purpose of the airline announcing it to passengers who are boarding and have thus already gone through security?

@JanusBahsJacquet Because it's not TSA's job to enforce airline operations specifications. The airline should, and the FAA makes it law that the passengers must abide by those rules. JetBlue misspoke about who the rule comes from, but they are still fundamentally correct that there's an official reason for the limit. It just comes from a different agency - FAA, not the TSA.

@Kuba The FAA regulation just states that you can’t board with more carry-on luggage than the airline allows. If the answer is correct that there is no specific requirements for what the OpsSpec for carry-on is, then the official reason for the limit comes entirely from JetBlue themselves – which would also be the usual situation and the reason why every airline has its own unique set of rules for carry-on. But that leaves the question unanswered: why does the airline then consistently claim that it’s due to TSA regulations?

@JanusBahsJacquet:  Airlines in particular, but many organizations, like to cite rules as government regulations because it makes it harder for customers to argue with.

@Ross True, but even with that in mind, TSA seems like an odd government entity to invoke, precisely because their part in the process is long over at the time the announcement is made to the passengers. Had they said it was due to FAA regulations, it would sound much more plausible even though it’s arguably hardly more accurate, since the FAA is at least actually responsible for various other things that apply at that stage of the journey.

@JanusBahsJacquet:  You are correct, but I think the people who make up the announcement text believe the TSA is more intimidating than the FAA.  Next time you fly, try explaining this to the person making the announcement and let me know how far you get.

@RossMillikan The main point of confusion for me when I made the original post was that a huge majority of Jetblue gate agents at different airports seem to cite "TSA regulations" when describing the on-board bag policy. If it's like a few or even half of gate agents who reference the TSA, it's believable that the agents are just making it up. But it looks like Jetblue's official pre-boarding announcement is saying that their baggage policy is due to the TSA. If anyone else flies Jetblue and hears something different please let me know. I'll listen again the next time I fly again in October.

@JanusBahsJacquet:  I believe the announcement has used TSA on most or all of the US airlines I have flown.  I am sure the wording is specified within each airline from above, though there might be some occasional variation.  Southwest used to be famous for ad-libs in the various announcements

@JanusBahsJacquet Carry-on luggage is not screened on arrival when flying domestically in the US.  However, if you arrive from a foreign country and go through immigration/customs, you will exit the secure area to do so.  If you then have a connecting flight inside the US (or even to another country, the US has no sterile transit), you will have to go through TSA security again.

@Aric That’s the same in lots of countries – but again, that’s screening on departure.

@JanusBahsJacquet Kind of.  It happens before you depart for your final destination, but it also happens shortly after you arrive in the US.  I could see discussions of this getting garbled and turning into "TSA screens luggage on arrival in the US".

I think whoever wrote this script simply confused TSA and FAA, and it's never been considered important enough to correct it. As long as the regulation comes from some federal agency, it's not really important for the passengers to know specifically which one. That could become significant if someone violates the rule and is prosecuted, but I don't think they could use the incorrect designation in the announcement as any kind of defense ("Oh, if I'd known it was actually an FAA regulation I wouldn't have violated it"). Anything regarding security is likely to be taken extra seriously (since 9/11 we put up with many inconveniences and indignities in the name of security), so passengers are more likely to heed a rule if they think it comes from TSA rather than FAA or the airline.
As others have pointed out, there is a TSA regulation regarding the items that may be taken through security screening, which may have contributed to the confusion. That regulation is moot by the time you're hearing the announcement on the plane (although passengers may remember it for future flights).


Passengers are also reminded to bring at maximum one carry-on bag and one personal item into security screening.

Source: tsa.gov

By the time you're on the plane hearing the announcement, you've already gone through security screening, so it's a little late for the warning.

TSA also doesn't let you bring water bottles through security screening, yet it's perfectly permissible to carry them onto the plane (having made a purchase from an air-side vendor).  People also buy items at duty-free and bring them onto the plane, and those didn't get counted by TSA during security screening.  So this rule has nothing to do with what can be carried onto the plane.

A simple counterexample:
It is legal to purchase an extra seat to carry something that you do not desire to check.  Commonly done with expensive musical instruments.  (There are instruments with high level frequent flyer status!)  Doing so doesn't mean giving up your normal baggage.

Yes, indeed. In fact, I do this with my cello on a regular basis. Based on the answers here and the comments under randomhead's answer, I doubt it is a rule that is mainly instated by the TSA.
